# Do particles fly uphill because of physics, not momentum?

Tags: particles

How do I set up the particle system so that they fly upwards in Blender 3D? I don't want the particles to fly upwards due to the Wind Force or just the momentum in the normal direction. I need the particles to fly upwards due to the settings. Like, for example, fire particles, even if the momentum of the particle was sideways, they would still fly uphill, due to the heat that lifts the particle up

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **Field Weights > Gravity** of your Fire System to -1.

[image]

Comment: or just set gravity to 0 and use velocity to set the speed

Comment: I updated my answer with a way that will not affect other physics objects.

Comment: Thanks_________